# How do I include images when using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I can't seem to get images to work when using cx_Freeze. I tried looking at another answer, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553886/how-can-i-bundle-other-files-when-using-cx-freeze), but got the error: cannot find file/directory named Documents\images\robot_standing.fw.png

Here is my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['Documents\images\robotStanding_sprite.fw.png', 'Documents\images\dirt_block.fw.png','Documents\images\grass_block.fw.png','Documents\images\spikes.fw.png','Documents\images\title_image.fw.png']
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = []

setup(
    name = 'Robot Game',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'null',
    options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables = [Executable('Robot Game.py')]
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The paths need to be relative to setup.py.

Comment: @ThomasK They are. Documents is the folder that setup.py is in, but I tried just images as well.

Comment: You need to escape \ to \\ or just use /

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.  I solved it in two steps:

1) I used a setup.py script based on the answer of Brian in [How do I use cx_freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895636/how-do-i-use-cx-freeze) and ran it as described by aquavitae in the same post.

2) I copied all of the image files manually into the build\exe.win32-3.3 directory where the executable and other auxiliary files resides.

Note: I used capital letters in the name of my source code file because I wanted the executable to have a name with capitals.  It worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use images with `.` in names of files because computer doesn't know what is extension.
You should name`'Documents\images\robotStanding_sprite.fw.png'` `'Documents\images\robotStanding_sprite_fw.png'`